# CSS rows not appearing on Safari, works fine on Chrome

Tags: html, css, angularjs

https://jsfiddle.net/suunyz3e/190/ - If you look at that fiddle in Safari, and resize the window down quite small you'll find the rows are overlapping each other... when what I want is for "TEST TEST TEST" to appear above "GO GO GO" (which is what it does perfectly on Chrome).

This problem is driving me crazy, if anyone knows how I can fix this I'd really appreciate it. I'm using Angular Material as the framework. Thanks.

```
<div ng-app="sandbox">
  <div layout="row" layout-xs="column">
    <div flex-gt-xs="30" flex-xs="100">
      TEST TEST TEST
    </div>       
    <div flex-gt-xs="70" flex-xs="100">
      GO GO GO
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
.layout-xs-column > .flex-xs-100 {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/naayt/6vfdzxho/2/